# How to remove text between brackets

Tags: java, regex

I want to process articles retrieved from the Wikipedia API, so that I can display just plain text. The stuff I want to remove looks somewhat like:

```
 {{Infobox scientist
     | name        = Albert Einstein
     | image       = Einstein 1921 by F Schmutzer.jpg
     | caption     = Albert Einstein in 1921
     | birth_date  = {{Birth date|df=yes|1879|3|14}}
     | birth_place = [[Ulm]], [[Kingdom of Württemberg]], [[German Empire]]
     | death_date  = {{Death date and age|df=yes|1955|4|18|1879|3|14}}
     | death_place = {{nowrap|[[Princeton, New Jersey]], United States}}
     | children    = [[Lieserl Einstein|"Lieserl"]] (1902–1903?)<br />[[Hans Albert Einstein|Hans Albert]] (1904–1973)<br />[[Eduard
 Einstein|Eduard "Tete"]] (1910–1965)
     | spouse      = [[Mileva Marić]]&nbsp;(1903–1919)<br />{{nowrap|[[Elsa Löwenthal]]&nbsp;(1919–1936)}}
     | residence   = Germany, Italy, Switzerland, Austria, Belgium, United States
     | citizenship = {{Plainlist|
     * [[Kingdom of Württemberg]] (1879–1896)
     * [[Statelessness|Stateless]] (1896–1901)
     * Switzerland (1901–1955)
     * [[Austria–Hungary]] (1911–1912)
     * [[German Empire]] (1914–1918)
     * [[Weimar Republic]] (1919–1933)
     * United States (1940–1955)
     }}
```

Now I want to know how to remove the text between `{{` and `}}`. This is what i have tried to do:

```
wikitext = wikitext.replaceAll("\\{\\{(.*?)\\}\\}", "");
```

But it's not really working. I guess that the "brackets in brackets" cause problems. There are a lot of discussions about removing the text between brackets on Stackoverflow, but I didn't find anything which could solve this problem

Comment: Which pair of `{{` and `}}` are you talking about? Inner or outer?

Comment: Are the leading `>` really there or are just trying to include code in your question?

Comment: No that was a mistake.

Comment: I am talking about all the text between the brackets. The example I included in my Question was to show the part I want to have deleted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not match with java regexes an undetermined level of nested brackets. However, for your specific example  that have only one depth level, and assuming that the closing brackets are missing at the end, you can use this:

```
\\{\\{(?>[^{}]++|\\{\\{[^}]++}})*}}
```

If the number of level is undetermined, you can:

1) write a parser that walks char by char and increase a stack when you meet `{{` and decrease when you meet `}}`. When the flag is equal to zero the brackets are balanced.

2) perform a replaceall until there is no more replacement to do with : `\\{\\{[^{}]*}}` *(that matches the innermost level)*

3) use a third party regex library that supports recursion

4) find a tool to deal with this format (perhaps it exists)

Answer (score 0):

I thought I would share my final resolution to this question. I used the first solution *Casimir et Hippolyte* suggested. This is my code:

```
private String removeTextBetweenTwoChars(String wikitext, char startChar, char endChar)
{
    char[] chararray = wikitext.toCharArray();//All characters in Wikipage
    char[] result = new char[chararray.length];;//Characters between spezified chars including those chars
    int stack = 0;//Stack for processing
    int resultCounter = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < chararray.length; i++)
    {
        char c = chararray[i];
        if (c == startChar && i+1 < chararray.length && chararray[i+1] == startChar)
        {
            stack++;
            i++;
        }
        else if (chararray[i] == endChar && i+1 < chararray.length && chararray[i+1] == endChar)
        {
            stack--;
            i++;
        }
        else if (stack == 0)
        {
            result[resultCounter] = chararray[i];
            resultCounter++;
        }
    }
    return new String(result);
}
```